# Im Stock at allocating memory c++

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

so for some reason I cannot allocate memory to new names
first I`m in gameEngine, then I ask the player to input 3 names. I`m sending the name to Setname, but for some reason the name isn't allocating.
what  I`m doing wrong?
this is only small part of the code, i cant show here the whole code.
Player::player

```
class Player
{
    int numInHand;
    char *name;
    Card** hand;
    }

        void gameEngine::startgame()
        {
            int i;
            char* Pname = new char[50];
            //cout << "How many players are playing? ";
            //cin >> howManyPlayers;
            howManyPlayers = 3;
            players = new Player*[howManyPlayers];
            for (i = 0; i < howManyPlayers; i++)
            {
                cout << "Enter player " << i + 1 << " name: ";
                cin >> Pname;
                players[i]->setName(Pname);  
            }

            char* Player::setName(char* Pname)
            {
                Newname= new char[strlen(Pname) + 1]; // allocating new nenamestring
                strcpy(Newname, Pname);
                delete[] Pname; // deleting old string

                return Newname;
            }

Player::Player(char* Pname)
{
    if (Pname)
        name = new char[(strlen(Pname) + 1)];
    else
        name = nullptr;
    numInHand = 0;
    hand = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: If you would ask you need to ensure that  the user typed a valid value. With that said you probably should not ask inside the constructor.

Comment: I assume that you are not permitted to use the `c++` standard library. Things like `std::string` and `std::vector` would make the program simpler and much better overall `c++` code.

Comment: I don`t understand your answers. I asked one thing and got answered for other thing.

Comment: If you have `cin >> howManyPlayers;` in your code a person could type -1 or perhaps a string like "fdsfsf" and your code does not care. It still attempts to continue with the garbage data causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

So the main error is here

```
        players = new Player*[howManyPlayers];
        for (i = 0; i < howManyPlayers; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter player " << i + 1 << " name: ";
            cin >> Pname;
            players[i]->setName(Pname);  
        }
```

This allocates `howManyPlayers` player **pointers**, but it does not allocate any actual players. But then here

```
            players[i]->setName(Pname);
```

your code assumes that you actually have some players, when you do not.

The answer is to cut back on the pointer usage. You have too many.

Change

```
 players = new Player*[howManyPlayers];
```

to

```
 players = new Player[howManyPlayers];
```

Now you are actually allocating players. Of course you'll also have to change the decalration of `players`. You might also have to add a default constructor to `Player` it's not clear if you have that or not.

Then change this

```
players[i]->setName(Pname);
```

to this

```
players[i].setName(Pname);
```

And no doubt many similar changes throughout your code.